# How do I programatically modify the SqlCacheDependency section of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcachedependency, web-config

I have this section in my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
      <sqlCacheDependency pollTime="60000" enabled="true">
        <databases>
          <add connectionStringName="CS" name="DB"/>
        </databases>
      </sqlCacheDependency>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```

I am trying to add a new entry in the `<databases>` element using this code

```
SqlCacheDependencySection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/caching/sqlCacheDependency") as SqlCacheDependencySection;
section.Databases.Add(new SqlCacheDependencyDatabase("DB2", "CS2", 60000));
```

But I receive an error that `databases` is read-only. The same goes for `pollTime` and `enabled` attributes.

So far I have managed to make them writable by setting the `_bReadOnly` private property to `false` using reflection

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField("_bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
fi.SetValue(section, false);
```

I'm not very comfortable using reflection to change the value of a private property in a sealed .net class. Also, I don't want to edit the web.config file using `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` because this would restart the worker process.

Is there another way to configure SqlCacheDependency in code behind?

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer, but maybe your problem can be solved by using [config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at deploy time.